# How to set timeout to 'ping' command?

Tags: macos, terminal, network, ping

In windows argument `-w` and number in milliseconds set how long wait echo reply from pinging host.

I'm running now macOS Sierra and `-t` argument from ping help set count of echo requests. So `ping google.com -c 5` and `ping google.com -t 5` give the same result - five echo requests with default timeout.

Is there a flag that does what I need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the man page for ping ([`man ping`](https://ss64.com/bash/ping.html)); under the `-i wait` option, we see that the default time between sending pings is 1 second:

> -i wait
>
> wait seconds between sending each packet.  The default is to wait for one second between each packet.

So, using the default of sending 1 packet every 1 second, the options `-t` and `-c` will produce the same output.

When we add in a *fractional* wait time of say, a half second, we should now get 12 packets sent within the 6 seconds:

```
$ sudo ping -i .5  -t 6 apple.stackexchange.com

PING apple.stackexchange.com (151.101.193.69): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=0 ttl=58 time=12.509 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=11.990 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=17.027 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=13.173 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=15.752 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=5 ttl=58 time=10.337 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=6 ttl=58 time=15.484 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=7 ttl=58 time=9.653 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=8 ttl=58 time=9.734 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=9 ttl=58 time=9.486 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=10 ttl=58 time=11.321 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=11 ttl=58 time=9.549 ms
```

Twelve responses as expected.  Note, that you must run this as `root`;    per the man page for the `-i wait` option:

> The [wait time may be fractional, but only the super-user may specify
>   values less than 1 second](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142703/).

Now, the `-W` option (capital "W", not lowercase) will be the equivalent to the Windows `-w` which specifies a wait time between receipt of the packets:

> -W waittime Time in milliseconds to wait for a *reply* for each packet sent. If a reply arrives later, the packet is not printed as replied,
>   but considered as replied when calculating statistics.